# DBF Files with dashes not working

Tags: c#, sql, dbf

Trying to do some work reading and writing DBF files and I found this sample: http://www.aspcode.net/reading-dbf-files-in-c

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection oConn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();
oConn.ConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=D:\databases\;Exclusive=No; Collate=Machine;NULL=NO;DELETED=NO;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;";
oConn.Open();
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand();
oCmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM D:\databases\thefile.dbf" ;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(oCmd.ExecuteReader());
oConn.Close();

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Only problem is it doesnt work if the file or folder name has a dash (-) in it. Is there a way I can make this query work with dashes in the names?

eg. DBF File: `C:\Temp\bowlpos\07-10\01-07-10.DBF`

Comment: Sorry, I'll include the snippet.

Comment: If you're specifying the folder and database type in the connection string, you should be able to just `SELECT * from [thefile-with-hyphens]` (without also including the drive and folder) by escaping with `[]`.

Comment: I then get this exception:
`ERROR [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC dBase Driver] The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object '05-05-11.DBF'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.`
Just using: SELECT * FROM [05-05-11.DBF]
With the config folder set to the folder.

Comment: I don't get that exception. I think @UnhandledException nailed it, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

try below

```
using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(
    @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + 
    @"Data Source=C:\Temp\bowlpos\07-10\01-07-10.DBF;" + 
    @"Extended Properties=dBASE III;"))
using (OleDbCommand cm = cn.CreateCommand())
{
    cn.Open();
    cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [01-07-10]";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cm.ExecuteReader());
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: Gave that a try and got the following exception:

`'C:\Temp\bowlpos\07-10\01-07-10.DBF' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.`

Comment: @d1k_is, small adjustment to UnhandledException's post.  Do NOT include the .DBF name in the connection source string.  Only include the path UP TO the dbf.  The query will look in the FOLDER it is connected to and look for the [01-07-10] dbf file.  I think it was just a copy/paste mistake.